# how to save multiple files in gridFS in one request?

Tags: node.js, gridfs

I am working with nodejs and mongodb and wants to store multiple files at one time. I am using GridFS for files.

My code works fine for single file upload. 
    var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: filename, metadata:project._id});
               console.log(tmpFilepath);

```
            var filename    = req.files.file.name;
            var tmpFilepath="./upload/"+ guid();
            fs.rename(req.files.file.path,tmpFilepath);
            fs.createReadStream(tmpFilepath)
              .on('end', function() {
             console.log("file Saved");
              })
              .on('error', function() {
               console.log("error encountered");
               // res.send('ERR');
              })
              // and pipe it to gfs
              .pipe(writestream);
                writestream.on('close', function (file) {
                fs.unlink(tmpFilepath);

              });
```

how can I make it work for uploading multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an aysnc call which is an npm module you can install.

```
var files = [];
async.each([].req.files.name, function(item){
    /* Apply your gridfs here */
    files.push('somedetails');
 }, 
 function(err){
    /* finished processing all the files...do something with them /*
    console.log(files);
});
```